# Reusing the service account in an SSRS data source

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

SQL Server 2016 reporting. The SSRS service runs as an account that has read access in the database I'd like to run reports from.

I'd like to create a server level data source object that would use the Windows service account to connect, instead of storing the credentials in the data source itself. Is there a way to do so?

The "Without any credentials" option doesn't work, I've tried.

Comment: We widely use shared data sources with database level service accounts authentication (using "credentials stored securely in the report server" option) and that just work fine for us.

Comment: I'd like to avoid storing the credentials in the data source itself.